# Prevent different font for equations and text

Tags: bibtex, viewers

**Please see the edit 2 below first.**
I am just beginning to learn TeX and I am working on a document that is based off a template I found [here](https://gist.github.com/jhwilson/1278588).
I am specifying my bibliography in a separate `.bib` file and I am using MikTeX for Windows to build a PDF. The problem that I am facing is the font used by bibliography page becomes grainy if I zoom in on generated PDF document. This is not the case with rest of the document. Only the bibliography has this problem. What could be causing this?
I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

and the name of my bib file is obviously `mybib.bib`.

**EDIT 1**
Here's sample tex file that I am using:

```
\documentclass{jhwhw} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage[scientific-notation=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Author Name}
\fancyhead[C]{Homework Title}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
\title{Homework Title}
\author{Author Name} % Your name
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Print the title
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\problem{Problem Title}
 <<Problem>>
\solution
 <<Solution>> 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**
Apparently this has nothing to do with bibliography and seems to affect anything outside `{equation}`. Take a look at screenshot below. The upper part is in equation whereas the lower is just text.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which PDF viewer are you using? Also, if possible, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble help at all?

Comment: The fonts not scaling well is usually an indication that bitmap (type 3) fonts are in use. But it isn't normal for the bibliography to be using a different font family to the rest of the document. You probably need to provide a more complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did read that I should be using Type 1 fonts for PDF. But I am not understanding how..

Comment: @cfr: Its already present in my preamble..

Comment: @Jubobs: I have added it. I don't quite understand everything in preamble. I just used it as is since it was a template. Btw, does PDF reader affect this behavior? I use SumatraPDF..

Comment: Mathematics and text use different fonts. After your edit #2 it seems like this has nothing to do with the bibliography, but that the issue has only to do with your text font (and not your math font), and you happened to notice it in the bibliography first. Anyway, we don't see the same as you do. There is no equation at all in the example you gave us, for instance.

Comment: Install with the package manager the cm-super package (large package!) .

Comment: @pst: You are correct. I just happened to notice it in bibliography. The equations and text would go under `\solution` section. I took all my content out for brevity.

Comment: Either do as @UlrikeFischer says or make sure `lmodern` is available and add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to your preamble.

Comment: @cfr: Adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` solved the problem. Can one of you post this as answer and perhaps explain why it works? Can you also include Ulrike's method in answer and why it works so that future visitors may benefit from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default and historically, TeX has used fonts in metafont format (`.mf`) and in `OT1` encoding. A font encoding tells TeX which slot in the font to find a particular character. For example, that the small letter a is in such-and-such number slot. `OT1` has 128 slots (7-bit) as TeX was originally 7-bit.

There are at least two issues with this:

1. 128 slots is not very many. It makes it difficult to cope with non-English languages, for example. The only way to produce â in traditional TeX was to take the a and the ^ and combine them. This isn't a fully satisfactory solution - often the result doesn't look quite right and it makes copy-pasting/searching fail.
2. Metafonts do not work well in PDF documents because they do not scale well. When TeX uses metafonts, it uses them at particular sizes which it generates on-the-fly. But the sizes are then fixed in the document. So when you zoom into the PDF, the result is jagged.

The solution to the first problem is to use the `T1` encoding which is 8-bit and has 256 slots. This allows it to support many more pre-composed accented characters. (Not all e.g. ŵ and ŷ, for example, are still excluded.)

The solution to the second is to use a type1 font. Such fonts are *scalable* so they can be scaled smoothly. When you zoom, the PDF viewer scales the font accordingly and there is no jaggedness.

## Initial document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

This document will use the default `OT1` encoding and will default to the basic metafont versions of Computer Modern. The resulting PDF will display the problem you saw in your text.

## Improving the code

Adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

will solve the first problem - TeX will use the `T1` encoding. Moreover, if they are available, TeX will automatically use type1 versions of Computer Modern. The standard package for this is `cm-super` mentioned by Ulrike Fische. Installing `cm-super` and adding the above line to your preamble will therefore solve both problems.

Depending on how your version of TeX is configured, merely installing `cm-super` may ensure that type1 fonts are used, even with the `OT1` encoding. This is true for recent versions of TeX Live, for example. However, `T1` is a superior encoding and should be preferred anyway.

## Alternative

Latin Modern is a more recent family of fonts in type1 (and opentype) format based on Computer Modern. If you have the fonts installed, adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

will result in type1 fonts from the Latin Modern family for both text and maths, as well as the `T1` encoding for text. Again, these are type1 so they scale smoothly and avoid the jaggedness you saw.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
\end{document}
```

The result at 1,600% magnification:

[image: Latin Modern type1 at 1,600%]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the detailed explanation.